# Use multiple sprite sheets at once in Cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, texturepacker

I'm making a platformer videogame in Cocos2d-x C++.

What I want to do is really easy but everything I have found on the internet either doesn't work or it's for another programming language like Objective-C.

I basically have multiple Spritesheets I'd like to use on my game. I can't merge them into 1 big spritesheet because they are really big.

I just want to know how to include multiple spritesheets so I can use them.

For using 1 spritesheet I use the following code:

```
// load and cache the texture and sprite frames
auto cacher = SpriteFrameCache::getInstance();
cacher->addSpriteFramesWithFile("GJ_GameSheet02-hd.plist");
```

I've read that I can use `SpriteBatch Node` for that, but I haven't found anything related to how to use that on C++.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the advanced feature of Texture Packer: generate .h and .cpp files.
But all you need is:

```
cache->addSpriteFramesWithFile("Graphics-0.plist", "Graphics-0.png");

cache->addSpriteFramesWithFile("Graphics-1.plist", "Graphics-1.png");
```

You only need to call addSpriteFramesWithFile multiple times with all your .plist files and .png

if you have a lot you can create a for loop:

```
void addSpriteFramesToCache(int i)
{
SpriteFrameCache *cache = SpriteFrameCache::getInstance();

    cache->addSpriteFramesWithFile("Graphics-" + std::to_string(i) + ".plist",
    "Graphics-" + std::to_string(i) + ".png");
}

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFramesToLoad; i++) //
{
    addSpriteFramesToCache(i);
}
```